# Use an apply function with user defined function that adds variables to data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, apply

I have defined a function which will dynamically create new variables in a data frame. For this function the input is a string which is then pasted with other strings to create variable names that already exist in the data frame which are then compared using case_when within mutate. The output of the function is the data frame with the new variable appended to the end. I want to apply this function to a vector of inputs, and create multiple new columns in the data frame. I have used the iris data set to create a function very similar to what I am doing.

```
func <- function(x) {
  a <- paste0("Sepal.", x)
  b <- paste0("Petal.", x)
  x <- iris %>% 
    mutate(
      !!(paste0("Compare.", x)) :=
        case_when(
          iris[[a]] > iris[[b]] ~ "Sepal",
          iris[[a]] < iris[[b]] ~ "Petal",
          TRUE ~ "Equal"
      )
    )
  return(x)
}

inputVector <- c("Length", "Width")
```

I want to apply this function to inputVector and have one data frame returned which would have the two new variables in it, preferably without loops. I'm looking to use something like

```
iris <- lapply(inputVector, func)
```

But this returns a list of two data frames. I also know that I could use `<<-` in `func`, but I would like to avoid this.

Comment: Careful, you're running `"SepalLength" > "PetalLength"`, not `Sepal.Length > Petal.Length`. Aside from the dots, you need to turn the strings to quosures and unquote them to refer to the variables instead of comparing the strings themselves.

Comment: Updated. Thank you for pointing this out. I was using base r for my actual work and made this example too quickly and missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slight change in the way you want to structure the output -

```
func <- function(x) {
  a <- paste0("Sepal", x)
  b <- paste0("Petal", x)
  x1 <- iris %>% 
    mutate(
      !!(paste0("Compare.", x)) :=
        case_when(
          a > b ~ "Sepal",
          a < b ~ "Petal",
          TRUE ~ "Equal"
        )
    )
  return(x1[[paste0('Compare.',x)]])
}

inputVector <- c("Length", "Width")
op <- iris
op[,paste0('Compare.',inputVector)] <- lapply(inputVector, func)
```

**Output**

```
> head(op)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species Compare.Length Compare.Width
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa          Sepal         Sepal
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa          Sepal         Sepal
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa          Sepal         Sepal
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa          Sepal         Sepal
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa          Sepal         Sepal
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa          Sepal         Sepal
```

Comment: Thank you! That is what I just figured out right before you posted I was answering my own question. Do you know if how you updated the data frame is better than what I did below using `do.call`?

Comment: @jamesguy0121 I would say the output format in the OP is more consistent with my answer for now. But you can always use `colnames()` to fix that with `do.call()`. I think both the solutions are good. You can try timing these two solutions to see which is faster in your case and go for the best one

Comment: Just so you know, mutate/transmute return tibbles, and since the variable is named in func, the name is preserved when called in `do.call(cbind, ....)`. Also I timed them for my case and they are basically the same at .1 I'm accepting your answer because I feel weird accepting my answer to my question. :) Thanks!

Comment: @jamesguy0121 I am glad I could help. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

A simpler option is to only generate the new columns in the function by substituting `transmute` for `mutate`, iterating and joining them into a data frame with `map_dfc`, and then using `bind_cols` to add them to the original:

```r
library(tidyverse)

func <- function(x) {
  a <- sym(paste0("Sepal.", x))    # these need to be quosures to refer to variables
  b <- sym(paste0("Petal.", x))
  iris %>% transmute(
      !!paste0("Compare.", x) := case_when(
          !!a > !!b ~ "Sepal",    # unquote quosures
          !!a < !!b ~ "Petal",
          TRUE ~ "Equal"
      )
    )
}

inputVector <- c("Length", "Width")

iris %>% bind_cols(map_dfc(inputVector, func)) %>% head()
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species Compare.Length
#> 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa          Sepal
#> 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa          Sepal
#> 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa          Sepal
#> 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa          Sepal
#> 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa          Sepal
#> 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa          Sepal
#>   Compare.Width
#> 1         Sepal
#> 2         Sepal
#> 3         Sepal
#> 4         Sepal
#> 5         Sepal
#> 6         Sepal
```

A slightly more elegant approach is to structure the function to take a vector, moving all the iteration inside. You could use the approach above, or just generate the vectors and assemble them into a data frame once there are multiple:

```r
func2 <- function(x) {
  columns <- map_dfc(x, function(y){
    a <- paste0("Sepal.", y)
    b <- paste0("Petal.", y)
    column <- list(case_when(
      iris[[a]] > iris[[b]] ~ "Sepal",    # base notation is simpler than quosures
      iris[[a]] < iris[[b]] ~ "Petal",
      TRUE ~ "Equal"
    ))
    names(column) <- paste0("Compare.", y)
    column
  })
  iris %>% bind_cols(columns)
}

func2(inputVector) %>% tail()
#>     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
#> 145          6.7         3.3          5.7         2.5 virginica
#> 146          6.7         3.0          5.2         2.3 virginica
#> 147          6.3         2.5          5.0         1.9 virginica
#> 148          6.5         3.0          5.2         2.0 virginica
#> 149          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3 virginica
#> 150          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8 virginica
#>     Compare.Length Compare.Width
#> 145          Sepal         Sepal
#> 146          Sepal         Sepal
#> 147          Sepal         Sepal
#> 148          Sepal         Sepal
#> 149          Sepal         Sepal
#> 150          Sepal         Sepal
```

Comment: Ahh, Great! Thank you. This is more what I was envisioning when I asked the question. I've been using R for a few years but am just diving into the tidyverse so there is still a lot of unknowns. Especially with the quosures and non standard evaluation. I will play with this for sure. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Playing around just a little bit more I did find the an answer to this question. Instead of having `func` output the data frame I changed it to output just the vector and then used `do.call` and `lapply`

```
func <- function(x) {
  a <- paste0("Sepal", x)
  b <- paste0("Petal", x)
  x <- iris %>% 
    transmute(
      !!(paste0("Compare.", x)) :=
        case_when(
          a > b ~ "Sepal",
          a < b ~ "Petal",
          TRUE ~ "Equal"
      )
    )
  return(x)
}

do.call(cbind, c(iris, lapply(inputVector, func)))
```

I am definitely open to alternative solutions, as I imagine that this is perhaps not the best.

Answer (score 0):

Your result is two data frames (as you indicated):

- `iris[[1]]` is the first dataframe
- `iris[[2]]` is the second dataframe.

You can use `merge` to merge both data frames into one, like this:

```
comp.iris <- lapply(inputVector, func) 
comp.iris <- merge(comp.iris[[1]], comp.iris[[2]], sort = FALSE)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I do not follow what you are trying to do and it didn't work. Looks like you are just merging the first to elements of x. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Ahh, ok I gotcha now. This does work, but in my actual use case I have a lot more variables that I am creating than just the two, so not really practical. Thanks.

Comment: I see your point. You may consider the alternatives then. Good luck!